# Typescript Quickstart Tutorial

Tags: typescript2.0

I am working with Visual Studio 2015, ASP.NET Core

When I walkthrough the Typescript Tutorial version 2.0.6.0 I have a problem with the function `sayHello` not producing the correct output.

```
function sayHello() {
    const compiler = (document.getElementById("compiler") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const framework = (document.getElementById("framework") as HTMLInputElement).value;

    return "Hello from ${compiler} and ${framework}!";
}
```

When I edit a textbox I see the following output:

> Hello from ${compiler} and ${framework}!

The variables are not replaced as would be expected.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: Instead of usual double quotes, you should use backticks, like this `return \`Hello from ${compiler} and ${framework}!\`;` These are the only one which are able to replace those placeholders with actual values, look into list of ES6 features to find out about backticks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use template strings surrounded by [backtick/backquote (`) characters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) to embed expressions within.

```
return `Hello from ${compiler} and ${framework}!`;
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to have been the problem.  Thanks!